# Multiple column of same table in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on sample railway database. I am stuck at retrieving some data. Table structure is

**Train :**

```
TrainId | TrainName | FromStationId | ToStationId | DeptTime | ArrivalTime
...
...
```

**RouteDetail :**

```
Id | TrainId | RouteOrder | FromStationId | ToStationId | TrackId
...
...
```

**Station :**

```
Id | name
...
...
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve this data but I haven't been successful yet.

```
TrainName | RouteOrder | FromStationName | ToStationName
```

Will really appreciate any help

Thanks.

Comment: _Im trying to retrieve this data but unsucessfull yet._  You should really include your attempts in your question.

Comment: sorry sir. that was unsuccessful attempts. thats why i didnt add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this. If no, you must provide more details.

```
SELECT 
    T.TrainName
    , RD.RoutOrder
    , S1.name as FromStationName
    , S2.name as ToStationName
FROM Train T
  LEFT JOIN RouteDetail RD
    ON T.TrainId = RD.TrainId
  LEFT JOIN Station S1
    ON RD.FromStationId = S1.Id
  LEFT JOIN Station S2
    ON RD.ToStationId = S2.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.trainname, r.routeorder, sfrom.name as fromstationname, sto.name as tostationname
from train t
inner join routedetail r on r.trainid = t.trainid
left join station sfrom on sfrom.id = fromstationid
left join station sto on sto.id = tostationid
```

Comment: thanks. this also worked but with some minor changes. thanks anyway..:)